# ReactJs - Side Bar responsive menu system in .map, same functions, cannot distinguish

Tags: reactjs

I have several menu items in a mapping with a click function to change the class to show sub-menu when click. However, all sub-menus are opening on click.

```
class SideNav extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        content: 'wrapper',
        navClass: 'vertical_nav',
        subMenuStatus :'menu--item  menu--item__has_sub_menu'
    };
  }

 //this is the function to open respective sub menu
  showSubMenu() {
    var index = this.state.subMenuStatus.indexOf('menu--subitens__opened');

    if(index != -1){
        this.setState({subMenuStatus: "menu--item  menu--item__has_sub_menu"});
    } else {
        this.setState({subMenuStatus: "menu--item  menu--item__has_sub_menu menu--subitens__opened"});
    }
}

..................
render(){
 return(
 {menuItems.map(function(menuItem, i) {
    if (menuItem.subMenus != undefined) {
      return (
        <li className={this.state.subMenuStatus} key={i}>
          <label onClick={this.showSubMenu.bind(this)} > <--- this guy
             <span className="menu--label">{menuItem.name}</span>
         </label>
            <ul className="sub_menu">
             .......
            </ul>
          </li>
        )
          }.bind(this))};
         ................
        )
     }
}
```

Comment: How are you differentiating between the menu items? the onClick handler isn't doing anything specific for that one subitem... they're all tied to the same state.

Comment: I know. And that is the problem I cannot see passed. Even with props, the all open when only one should.

Comment: Is `menuItems` a store or something? I would probably turn the `<li> ... </li>` into it's own menu item component and use it's internal state to do the display.

Comment: I was going to refactor after I got this fixed. Even combined as one component, there has to be a way to do this.

Comment: Can you make `subMenuStatus` an object that is key/value pair and set to the key to each sub menu?

Comment: I'll try to come up with an example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the sub menu's are sharing the same class state. I would turn the `subMenuStatus` into an object that is linked to each menu.

```js
class SideNav extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    
    // iterate through menuItems and build the status
    var subMenuStatus = {};
    menuItems.map(function(menuItem) {
      subMenuStatus[i.someKey] = 'menu--item  menu--item__has_sub_menu';
    });
    this.state = {
        content: 'wrapper',
        navClass: 'vertical_nav',
        subMenuStatus : subMenuStatus
    };
  }

 //this is the function to open respective sub menu
  showSubMenu(menuItem) {
    var index = this.state.subMenuStatus[menuItem.someKey].indexOf('menu--subitens__opened');
    var newStatus = this.state.subMenuStatus;
    if(index != -1){
        newStatus[menuItem.someKey] = "menu--item  menu--item__has_sub_menu";
    } else {
        newStatus[menuItem.someKey] = "menu--item  menu--item__has_sub_menu menu--subitens__opened";
    }
    this.setState({subMenuStatus: newStatus});
}

..................
render(){
 return(
 {menuItems.map(function(menuItem, i) {
    if (menuItem.subMenus != undefined) {
      return (
        <li className={this.state.subMenuStatus[menuItem.someKey} key={menuItem.someKey}>
          <label onClick={this.showSubMenu.bind(this, menuItem)} > <--- this guy
             <span className="menu--label">{menuItem.name}</span>
         </label>
            <ul className="sub_menu">
             .......
            </ul>
          </li>
        )
          }.bind(this))};
         ................
        )
     }
}
```

This is untested, but I hope you get the picture.

Comment: Brad, I am giving you credit for your answer, but it wasn't totally correct, plus I was able to enhance my menu by closing the previous submenus that may have been opened when the new one was clicked, in case you do not want multiple submenus opened. I will paste the entire code now. Thanks

Comment: Ok great! I'm glad you at least were able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: This is a converted example of:
>   http://www.cssscript.com/responsive-sidebar-navigation-with-javascript-and-css3/

**I gave Brad credit because he showed me the way, although his code was not totally correct. Plus, I enhanced my menu so previously opened submenus are closed when a new submenu is clicked to be opened.**

```
'use strict';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

var menuItems = [
  {name: 'Item 1', subMenus: [{name: 'Sub Menu 1-2'}, {name: 'Sub Menu 1-2'}, {name: 'Sub Menu 1-3'}]},
  {name: 'Item 2'},
  {name: 'Item 3'},
  {name: 'Item 4', subMenus: [{name: 'Sub Menu 4-2'}, {name: 'Sub Menu 4-2'}, {name: 'Sub Menu 4-3'}]},
  {name: 'Item 5'}
]


class SideNav extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    var subMenuStatus = {};
    menuItems.map(function(menuItem, i) {
        menuItem.someKey = i
        subMenuStatus[menuItem.someKey] = 'menu--item  menu--item__has_sub_menu';
    });
    this.state = {
        content: 'wrapper',
        navClass: 'vertical_nav',
        subMenuStatus : subMenuStatus
    };
}
```

---

```
collapseSideBar() {
      var index = this.state.content.indexOf(' wrapper__minify');

      if (index != -1) {
          this.setState({content: 'wrapper'});
          this.setState({navClass: 'vertical_nav vertical_nav__opened'});
      } else {
          this.setState({content: 'wrapper wrapper__minify'});
          this.setState({navClass: 'vertical_nav vertical_nav__opened vertical_nav__minify'});
    }
}
```

---

```
toggleMobileMenu() {
    var index = this.state.content.indexOf('toggle-content');

    if (index != -1) {
        this.setState({navClass: 'vertical_nav'});
        this.setState({content: 'wrapper'});
    } else {
        this.setState({navClass: 'vertical_nav vertical_nav__opened'});
        this.setState({content: 'wrapper toggle-content'});
    }
}
```

---

```
showSubMenu(selMenuItem) {
    var newStatus = this.state.subMenuStatus;
    var index = this.state.subMenuStatus[selMenuItem.someKey].indexOf('menu--subitens__opened');

   // Enhancement- close previously opened sub menu
    menuItems.forEach(function(menuItem){
        if (selMenuItem.someKey != menuItem.someKey) {
            newStatus[menuItem.someKey] = "menu--item  menu--item__has_sub_menu";
        }
    })

    if(index != -1){
        newStatus[selMenuItem.someKey] = "menu--item  menu--item__has_sub_menu";
    } else {
        newStatus[selMenuItem.someKey] = "menu--item  menu--item__has_sub_menu menu--subitens__opened";
    }
    this.setState({subMenuStatus: newStatus});
}
```

---

```
// close any open submenu when non-parent menu is clicked
closeAllSubMenus() {
    var newStatus = this.state.subMenuStatus;
    menuItems.forEach(function (menuItem) {
            newStatus[menuItem.someKey] = "menu--item  menu--item__has_sub_menu";
    })
    this.setState({subMenuStatus: newStatus});
}
```

---

```
  render() {
    return (
        <section>
            <header className="header clearfix">
                <button type="button" id="toggleMenu" onClick={this.toggleMobileMenu.bind(this)} className="toggle_menu">
                    <i className="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <h1>Vertical Responsive Menu</h1>
            </header>
            <nav className={this.state.navClass}>
                <ul id="js-menu" className="menu">
                    {menuItems.map(function (menuItem, i) {
                        if (menuItem.subMenus != undefined) {
                            return (
                                <li className={this.state.subMenuStatus[menuItem.someKey]} key={menuItem.someKey}>

                                    <label className="menu--link" onClick={this.showSubMenu.bind(this, menuItem)}>
                                        <i className="menu--icon  fa fa-fw fa-user"></i>
                                        <span className="menu--label">{menuItem.name}</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <ul className="sub_menu">
                                        {menuItem.subMenus.map(function (subMenu, i) {
                                            return (
                                                <li className="sub_menu--item" key={i}>
                                                    <a href="#"
                                                       className="sub_menu--link sub_menu--link__active">{subMenu.name}</a>
                                                </li>
                                            )
                                        })}
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            )
                        } else {
                            return (
                               <li className="menu--item" key={i} onClick={this.closeAllSubMenus.bind(this)}>
                                    <a href="#" className="menu--link" title={menuItem.name}>
                                        <i className="menu--icon  fa fa-fw fa-briefcase"></i>
                                        <span className="menu--label">{menuItem.name}</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            )
                        }
                    }.bind(this))};

                </ul>
                <button id="collapse_menu" className="collapse_menu" onClick={this.collapseSideBar.bind(this)}>
                    <i className="collapse_menu--icon  fa fa-fw"></i>
                    <span className="collapse_menu--label">Recolher menu</span>
                </button>
            </nav>
            <div className={this.state.content}>
                <h3>Vertical Responsive Menu Demo Page</h3>

                <p>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their party</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
  }
}

module.exports = SideNav;
```

***Of course, you might want to refactor this. Hope it helps because Lords knows documentation is scant.***

**Also note I am using:**

```
"react": "^0.14.0-beta3",
"react-dom": "^0.14.0-beta3",
"react-router": "^1.0.0-beta3",
"react-document-title": "^2.0.0",
```